# javax.xml.crypto.URIReferenceException: Cannot resolve element with ID Object

Tags: java, rsa, digital-signature

I wanted to Do a digital signature on the XML File by

1. one way hashing with SHA-256
2. Canonicalization Method Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xmlexcc14n#"
3. RSA Digital signature
4. 2048-bit private key
5. W3C Recommendation XML Signature Syntax
6. Enveloping type signature.

I followed the Signature api mentioned [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/security/java-xml-digital-signature-api-overview-and-tutorial.htm#JSSEC-GUID-DB46A001-6DBD-4571-BDBC-1BBC394BF61E)!

But I get the following error

com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.security.utils.resolver.ResourceResolverException: Cannot resolve element with ID object

I have already tried Element.setIdAttributeNode for the "ID" and also the setIdAttributeNS but didn't help

The below line is where the error is thrown

```
DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
dbFactory.setNamespaceAware ( false );  
Document doc = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder().parse(new FileInputStream(filePath));

String providerName = System.getProperty("jsr105Provider", "org.jcp.xml.dsig.internal.dom.XMLDSigRI");

XMLSignatureFactory fac = XMLSignatureFactory.getInstance("DOM", (Provider) Class.forName(providerName).newInstance());

// Next, create a Reference to a same-document URI that is an Object element and specify the SHA256 digest algorithm
DigestMethod digestMethod = fac.newDigestMethod(DigestMethod.SHA256, null);
Reference reference = fac.newReference("#CBC",digestMethod);
SignatureMethod signatureMethod = fac.newSignatureMethod("http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256", null);
CanonicalizationMethod canonicalizationMethod = fac.newCanonicalizationMethod(CanonicalizationMethod.INCLUSIVE_WITH_COMMENTS, (C14NMethodParameterSpec) null);

// Create the SignedInfo
SignedInfo si = fac.newSignedInfo(canonicalizationMethod, signatureMethod, Collections.singletonList(reference));

// Create a RSA KeyPair
KeyPairGenerator kpg = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
kpg.initialize(2048);
KeyPair kp = kpg.generateKeyPair();

// Create a KeyValue containing the RSA PublicKey that was generated
KeyInfoFactory kif = fac.getKeyInfoFactory();
KeyValue kv = kif.newKeyValue(kp.getPublic());

// Create a KeyInfo and add the KeyValue to it
KeyInfo ki = kif.newKeyInfo(Collections.singletonList(kv));
DOMSignContext dsc = new DOMSignContext(kp.getPrivate(), doc);
//dsc.setDefaultNamespacePrefix("dsig");

// Create the XMLSignature and sign it
XMLSignature signature = fac.newXMLSignature(si, ki,Collections.singletonList(obj), null, null);
signature.sign(dsc);

TransformerFactory tf = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
Transformer trans = tf.newTransformer();
```

The error is occurring at the below line

```
signature.sign(dsc)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added the below 2 lines and it solved the issue.

```
XMLStructure content = new DOMStructure(doc.getDocumentElement());
XMLObject obj = fac.newXMLObject(Collections.singletonList(content), "CBC", null, null);
```